# Running an IDE on MacOS from Docker

Tags: java, docker

I am working on a project  which has a particular filesystem requirement. In order to build the project, I will have to create various sub-file systems on my Mac. However, I do not want to meddle with the file system on my actual mac as I could corrupt it. Hence, I want to use a docker container.

I use eclipse as my IDE. However, in order to use the docker file system in my IDE - I have to run the IDE from within the container. (I am able to do that successfully by following [this](https://blog.alexellis.io/linux-desktop-on-mac/)

However, this is super super super slow, and I cannot develop on the IDE running inside the container.

Is there a way to use my IDE by running it outside the docker container (on my actual machine) BUT link it to the file system and directories of the container?

Comment: I can understand that your project has a particular filesystem, but why does that require your IDE to run in a Docker container? Why can't you just develop as usual, and then deploy your application in the Docker container?

Comment: use the IDE from your machine and simply share the files from docker to your machine (check volume) or even ssh in the machine if you have an openssl or something

Answer (score 1):

Having *everything* inside a docker container can quickly lead to absolutely horrible IO performance. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/) for in-depth details.

We have a similar problem: a really large project, that can be built using a predefined docker infrastructure. But having the docker container work on the native MacOS filesystem is several times slower compared to running the same docker setup on a Linux machine (just because the IO from the docker to the underlying file system).

Our solution: the source code lives and gets edited directly on MacOS filesystem. Then there is a docker *volume* that contains a *copy* of the project. And: a permanent docker instance that does nothing else but `rsync` the two sides. Of course, the first `rsync` takes its time, but afterwards, it is just about small changes on either side.

Long story short: I suggest to "reverse" things. Don't move your IDE into docker, but move the source code *out* of docker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you have documentation on how to do the rsync with a docker container?

Comment: You might want to remind me next week. Of course, a good way to remind me would be to accept the answer, or at least upvote it :-)